# Why is this readline iterating in the way it is, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
with open('deltas11min.txt', 'r') as f:
         
         for line in f:
          
          
             f_str = str(f.readline())

             firstchar = f_str[:1]
             
                 
             if firstchar == 'a':
```

etc...

While running this through Spyder, I found that when it runs the line `firstchar = f_str[:1]`, instead of assigning the first character value of the first line of the text file, it instead reads the next line and assigns that as `f_str`.

Why is this happening, and how can I do something like the above? I want to read one line from a text file, then record the first character as a variable.

Comment: The for loop already reads the lines of the file. Doing so explicitly again means reading lines at twice the "speed" - i.e. having only every second element.

Answer (score 1):

`open` returns an iterable that yields all the lines in your file. Your `for` loop already iterates over the lines in your file, so you don't need to call `readline`.

```py
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("a"):
        # Do something...
```

`readline` tells the interpretor to go to the next line and then read it. It's mostly used when you have a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f:
    firstchar = line[0] # Use first index, not list splicing
    if firstchar == 'a':
        #  ...
```

Comment: While the code solves the immediate problem, code-only answers rely on people understanding the kind of code they struggled with in the first place. Consider to add a description of the misunderstanding that lead to the issue, as well as the key components of the new code.